# How can I make the picture run perfectly on the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make the background perfect for the running screen, but the vertical axis of the picture doesn't stretch even if I keep changing it in the code.
How can I get it right?

```py
import pygame
SCREEN_WIDTH = 500
SCREEN_HEIGHT  = 600
pygame.init()
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("pygame test")

screen=  pygame.image.load("그림.png")
```

```py
SCREEN.blit(screen,(0,100))
SCREEN.blit(player, player_Rect)
pygame.display.flip()
```

if i add `screen=pygame.transform.scale(500,600)` this code
print black screen

Comment: If the image isn't the same size as the screen, what does "get it right" mean?

Answer (score 1):

`pygame.transform.scale()` takes two arguments, the source surface and a tuple with the size of the new and scaled surface:

<s>`screen=pygame.transform.scale(500,600)`</s>

```py
screen = pygame.transform.scale(screen, (500, 600))
```

Scale the surface immediately after loading it:

```py
screen = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("그림.png").convert_alpha(), (500, 600))
```